# magento 2 production mode cache and browser cache

Tags: magento2, browser-cache

I have a nginx + varnish setup for magento 2. The site is in production mode. Everything worked pretty nicely until I made a small change to css file. The modification is not loaded by anyway to the clients.

From browser private mode I can see the changes, but from "old" normal browser sessions I see only the old layout. When I empty the browser cache, I can see the new css layout. However, I cannot go to every client's computer to empty cache for them.

What can I do in this case to force a expiry of css? Through header? recompilation? static file numbering? Someone had this issue before?

I tried redeployment of static contents, flush the server cache and flush varnish cache. Those did not work.

Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: I am just gonna leave it here as a workaround: I set the site to dev mode, fiddle the option of merge js/css, deploy under dev mode. set the option back to merge and version js/css file, then set it back to production mode. wipe in advance the generated static files before hand, of course. under production mode, redeploy, then it works. This is definitely not a solution, only use it when you have not such a busy site and can afford some down time and handler exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "expires" in this css file header. 
You should be able to add Nginx option for contriling the cacher expiration date for different types of files. 
Paste the next code into the server block:

```
#browser caching of static assets
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1d;
```

}

Comment: Hi @sudmak, many thanks first of all. I have the following snippet in the nginx config `add_header Cache-Control "max-age=600, public"; expires +1y;`.